# Where does compilation start from ? top of the file? (or) from the class containing main? (or) public class?

Tags: java, constructor, compilation

I am confused in the order of compilation of .java file.  Where does compilation  start from ? top of the file? (or) from the class containing main? (or)  public class?

```
--- * File Sample1.java *---
class A 
{ 
   public static void main(String args[])
   { 
      String str[] = {""}; 
      System.out.println("hi"); 
      B.main(str); 
   } 
} 
class B 
{ 
   public static void main(String args[]) 
   { 
     System.out.println("hello");
   }
}
```

My assumptions compiling "Sample1.java":
1)  Code start executing from the top. so class A is compiled then class B.

Then how do I consider the below code compiles?

```
--- * File Sample2.java *---
class A extends class B
{ 
int a; 
} 
class B 
{
int b; 
}
```

Adding to this I have one more question:

compiler creates a default constructor for `A` in which there is a call to its superclass constructor(class `B`), So is this call placed by compiler or just JVM tries to call it at run time.

Comment: Order of compilation (not sure if that even makes sense, many classes have recursive dependencies and need to be compiled together) has nothing to do with order of execution. Remember that Java is a compiled language, and running the program happens separately from compilation.

Comment: "is this call placed by compiler or just JVM tries to call it at run time". Both. The implicit constructor call is inserted by the compiler. In the compiled class it is explicitly present. The JVM does not try to execute code that is not there. But of course, the execution itself happens at runtime by the JVM.

Comment: Also note that you are making a method call to `out.println`. The code for that method is not compiled by your compiler, that has been done by the developers of the JDK who put the resulting class file for your compiler to use into the standard library jars.

Comment: @JimGarrison Why not? None of them is public.

Comment: @JimGarrison A `.java` source file can contain an infinite number of top-level types, but when using a file system, only one of them can be `public` and that types name must match the file name.

Comment: _is this call placed by compiler or just JVM tries to call it at run time_
- 
You can check the compiled code by using javap. Run "javap -c -p A.class" to get the bytecodes of all the methods in class A. You will see A's default constructor calling B's constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compilation *starts* from the top of the file, but it goes through several phases. When the compiler first reads the classes, it only checks that it can parse the syntax, and builds an internal tree from it.
In a later phase, it will try to resolve symbols and then it checks whether they exist.

Your example (corrected for syntax - you can't say "extends **class** B"):

```
class A extends B { 
    int a; 
} 
class B {
    int b; 
}
```

works fine, because the compiler doesn't need to know whether class `B` exists in the first phase, when it is reading the text of class `A`. In a later phase, when the compiler tries to resolve the symbol `B` from the `class A extends B`, it looks `B` up and since it already read the text of class `B` at that point, it finds it and compiles the code correctly.

Comment: Compile the file, run `ls -lT` and you'll get the time of the compiled class files.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the following yucky code:

> A.java

```
public interface A {
    A ZERO = new B();
    void f(A a);
}
```

> B.java

```
public class B implements A {
    public f(A a) {
        g();
    }
    void g() {
    }
```

}

The compilation happens inside a java source file:

- Parsing: Abstract Syntax Tree constructed by reading top-down.
- Semantic analysis by processing the syntax tree.

The local package and the imports provide other classes, that might need compilation too.

The compiled product, a .class file, contains field and method names and their signatures. It refers to imported classes by field and method names and their signatures. In classical terms it is an .o / .obj object file, that still needs a form of linking. In java that is checked by the compiler, whether an imported class is used correctly.

The weakness of this is, that when a .class is later exchanged outside this compilation process (i.e. as it is inside a library jar), then at runtime the jvm might give an error exception.

The order of java sources to compile is free, as the above cyclic reference demonstrates. The application entry point `main` is irrelevant.

So compilation is a breadth-first process on several files, not a depth-first process entirely treating one .java. It can produce a .class file in one step, but checking the imported method signatures must be postponed till the imports are compiled.

As there are several java compilers more cannot be said.